# Samsung Galaxy S5 Won't Update

Tags: updates

Every time I try to update my Samsung Galaxy S5, it says I don't have enough storage. One day, I cleared enough storage and proceeded with the update. However, I walked a way to grab something and when I returned, it said the update failed. I have AT&T, and when I looked online for solutions to this problem, AT&T was common in most of the issues. 
Also, my current Android version is Lollipop (5.0), and, at this time, the newest is Marshmallow. How can I fix this?

If you need any more info to help, just ask.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For a quick recommendation you could back up your info then factory restore your phone.  That is what I would do if I had that issue.

Comment: Head over to [sammobile/firmware](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/) and enter your specific model number. Then download the newest available Firmware and follow the instructions given on the download page